# Streaming the Web API Return Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are currently querying an Oracle DB and returning the result in JSON format. The Controller is something like below

```
public HttpResponseMessage Getdetails([FromUri] string[] Column)
{
    DataTable selectResults = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(selectResults);
    var returnObject = new { data = selectResults };
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, returnObject, MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json"));
    ContentDispositionHeaderValue contentDisposition = null;
    if (ContentDispositionHeaderValue.TryParse("inline; filename=Data.json", out contentDisposition))
    {
       response.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = contentDisposition;
    }
    return response;
}
```

I want to Stream the Result from the Web API so there is no memory issues. I found [this](http://blog.guvweb.co.uk/2014/07/02/streaming-web-api/) using `StreamContent`. So do I just change the `GetDetails` in to `StreamContent`. Do we give the path explicitly in the API Call.